# Checking if ARM is in supervisor mode or interrupt mode during kernel bootup

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, arm, armv7

I have to check whether the ARM processor is in SVC or IRQ mode during kernel bootup. That is, I want to insert some code to check the ARM mode into `start_kernel()` function before the interrupts are enabled and after the interrupts are enabled.

I know that I need the **SPSR** or **CPSR** values(bits) to check the mode in ARM, but how can I write code for that in `start_kernel` function since the code for reading bits of CPSR/SPSR is in assembly? Where do I put the assembly code to check the ARM mode during bootup time? Is there any way to dump the SPSR/CPSR values?

Comment: This should be trivial using inline assembly. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @cody I have put  `asm (" mrs %0, cpsr\n" : "=r" (rval));
                  printk(KERN_NOTICE "%u", rval);` after some function in start_kernel function, but no output is seen during bootup.

Comment: I am using  ARM GNU/Linux tool chain and arm-linux-gnueabi cross compiler.

Comment: You need to go to 'kernel hacking' and turn on POLLED or low-level debug (DEBUG_LL).  Then you can alter [*kernel/printk/printk.c* in function `vprintk_emit`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/printk/printk.c?id=2f1d70af28a94988c1e8fba2ae03d4c7e68e690b#n1491) and add a line `printascii(text)` (at 1549 in current mainline).  Then you will have more success working through your boot issues.  Also need `extern void printascii(char *);` somewhere of course.  When interrupts are active you get double console output, then you need tor remove `printascii`.

Comment: @artlessnoise I have done this and its not related to my question at all.I want contents of cpsr not some debugging info.

Comment: `but no output is seen during bootup` is caused by printk buffering which will only be output when interrupts are enabled unless you enable DEBUG_LL and use `printascii`.  Otherwise, your `asm` seems to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't dare imagine why this should be a concern, but fortunately there's an easy answer:

**It's in SVC mode.**

The [very first thing](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/head.S?h=v4.9#n80)<sup>*</sup> the kernel entrypoint does is to [forcibly switch into SVC mode and mask interrupts](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/assembler.h?h=v4.9#n335). To somehow be in the wrong mode by the time you reach C code in `start_kernel` way later would need the system to be unimaginably horribly broken. The only way I can conceive of that even being possible is if there is some Secure firmware running asynchronously (e.g. off a Secure timer interrupt) which deliberately corrupts the Non-secure state, and that's sufficiently ridiculous to discount.

<sub>* OK, the second thing if the kernel is built with KVM support and entered in HYP, but hey...</sub>

Comment: Actually I know that it will be in SVC mode but I need to dump the CPSR/SPSR contents after the interrupts are enabled. Can you tell me how to dump those values in any of the startup functions(might be assembly also) because I am booting the kernel on kzma-9 board and I need to see it as kernel message (when I run dmesg).

Comment: I dont need the checking of mode to be in start_kernel function only. It can be in any of startup code. I just want to see the contents of CPSR/SPSR as kernel message.

Comment: @karthikpj If you want it to appear in dmesg, then it will need to go via regular `printk()`, which basically rules out doing it from assembly. Since `printk()` needs stuff like locks and percpu variables to be ready, calling it too early might well result in a crash - to be safe, I wouldn't put it any earlier than the initial call printing `linux_banner`. Remember to newline-terminate your format string so it doesn't get munged into whatever message follows.

Comment: Exactly why I describe how to modify `vprintk_emit()` so that early printk messages are seen.  Also you can use `printascii()` directly to verify the code point is reached.

Comment: @Notlikethat Do you know by any chance where the interrupts are enabled in startup code? Actually I am trying to print address of each function during the kernel boot but after **setup_arch()** call in **start_kernel** function where vector table for interrupts are initialized, addresses are getting printed randomly without stop(infinitely). Can you point me as to where the problem might be?

Comment: [ARM specific IRQ initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423059/arm-specific-irq-initialization); you should up vote **the question** if it is useful to you.

Answer (score -1):

after the boot the ARM processor is in secure SVC mode during this mode you can access CPSR register(first 6 bits) to check in which mode however when the kernel is runing you are in user non-secure mode and in this mode non secure you can't access the the CPSR and SPSR register and also copro 15 register .

The only way is to write a code that generate an exception to switch monitor mode " using SMC assebmbly instruction" to jump to monitor secure mode then in that mode you reset the "NS" bit to switch to non-secure then you generate another exception to switch the SVC mode(SVC instruction assembly call) now you are in supervisor secure mode and you can then access CPSR and SPSR register