# kernel entry points on ARM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, interrupt

I was reading through the ARM kernel source code in order to better my understanding and came across something interesting.

Inside `arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S` there is a macro named `vector_stub`, that generates a small chunk of assembly followed by a jump table for various `ARM` modes. For instance, there is a call to `vector_stub irq, IRQ_MODE, 4` which causes the macro to be expanded to a body with label `vector_irq`; and the same occurs for `vector_dabt`, `vector_pabt`, `vector_und`, and `vector_fiq`.

Inside each of these vector_* jump tables, there is exactly 1 `DWORD` with the address of a label with a `_usr` suffix.

I'd like to confirm that my understanding is accurate, please see below.

1. Does this mean that labels with the `_usr` suffix are executed, only if the interrupt arises when the kernel thread executing on that CPU is in userspace context? For instance, `irq_usr` is executed if the interrupt occurs when the kernel thread is in userspace context, `dabt_usr` is executed if the interrupt occurs when the kernel thread is in userspace context, and so on.
2. If [1] is true, then which kernel threads are responsible for handling, say irqs, with a different suffix such as `irq_svc`. I am assuming that this is the handler for an interrupt request that happens in SVC mode. If so, which kernel thread handles this? The kernel thread currently in SVC mode, on whichever CPU receives the interrupt?
3. If [2] is true, then at what point does the kernel thread finish processing the second interrupt, and return to where it had left off(also in SVC mode)? Is it `ret_from_intr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Inside each of these vector_* jump tables, there is exactly 1 `DWORD` with the address of a label with a `_usr` suffix.

This is correct.  The table in indexed by the current mode.  For instance, `irq` only has three entries;  `irq_usr`, `irq_svc`, and `irq_invalid`.  Irq's should be disabled during data aborts, FIQ and other modes.  Linux will **always** transfer to svc mode after this brief 'vector stub' code.  It is accomplished with,

```
@
@ Prepare for SVC32 mode.  IRQs remain disabled.
@
mrs r0, cpsr
eor r0, r0, #(\mode ^ SVC_MODE | PSR_ISETSTATE)
msr spsr_cxsf, r0

@@@ ... other unrelated code

movs    pc, lr          @ branch to handler in SVC mode
```

This is why `irq_invalid` is used for all other modes.  Exceptions should never happen when this vector stub code is executing.

> Does this mean that labels with the _usr suffix are executed, only if the interrupt arises when the kernel thread executing on that CPU is in userspace context? For instance, irq_usr is executed if the interrupt occurs when the kernel thread is in userspace context, dabt_usr is executed if the interrupt occurs when the kernel thread is in userspace context, and so on.

Yes, the `spsr` is the interrupted mode and the table indexes by these mode bits.

> If [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928904/linux-kernel-arm-exception-stack-init) is true, then which kernel threads are responsible for handling, say irqs, with a different suffix such as irq_svc. I am assuming that this is the handler for an interrupt request that happens in SVC mode. If so, which kernel thread handles this? The kernel thread currently in SVC mode, on whichever CPU receives the interrupt?

I think you have some misunderstanding here.  There is a 'kernel thread' for user space processes.  The `irq_usr` is responsible for storing the user mode registers as a reschedule might take place.  The context is different for `irq_svc` as a kernel stack was in use and it is the same one the IRQ code will use.  What happens when a user task calls `read()`?  It uses a system call and code executes in a kernel context.  Each process has both a user and svc/kernel stack (and thread info).  A kernel thread is a process without any user space stack.

> If [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423059/arm-specific-irq-initialization) is true, then at what point does the kernel thread finish processing the second interrupt, and return to where it had left off(also in SVC mode)? Is it `ret_from_intr`?

Generally Linux returns to the kernel thread that was interrupted so it can finish it's work.  However, there is a configuration option for pre-empting svc threads/contexts.  If the interrupt resulted in a reschedule event, then a process/context switch may result if `CONFIG_PREEMPT` is active.  See `svc_preempt` for this code.

See also:

- [Linux kernel arm exception stack init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928904/linux-kernel-arm-exception-stack-init)
- [Arm specific irq initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423059/arm-specific-irq-initialization)